# how to eliminate slashes \ from a jsonlite string

Tags: r, json, jsonlite, plumber

When I convert a dataframe with jsonlite to a json-string, the jsonstring looks correct if I print it in the console. See:

```
library(jsonlite) # for JSON parsing

    # Create a data frame
    df <- data.frame (
      Training = c("Strength", "Stamina", "Other"),
      Pulse = c(100, 150, 120),
      Duration = c(60, 30, 45)
    )
    
    df_json <- toJSON(df, pretty=FALSE)
    myvar <<- df_json
    print(df_json)

    >
    [{"Training":"Strength","Pulse":100,"Duration":60},{"Training":"Stamina","Pulse":150,"Duration":30},{"Training":"Other","Pulse":120,"Duration":45}]
```

Although the output has slashes \ in the Environment:
[image]

When I use plumber to host the json-string, it also shows these slashes in the output.
Is there a way to eliminate the slashes? I am looking for output which I can read as a json-string.

Thanks a lot!

```
library(plumber)
library(dplyr)

#* @param symbol Ticker symbol (just to input something in the function)
#* @get /return
#* @serializer json
financial_data <- function(symbol) {
  data <- myvar
  data 
}
```

Comment: The slashes aren't actually in the string. That's just how R escapes special characters while printing. Use `cat(df_json)` to see the value without escaping. But your plumber code seem to double encode the data. `toJSON` will return a string and then you are using the `@serialize json` to re-encode that string again. Store the data itself instead `myvar <<- df`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I left out @serialize json AND I left out df_json <- toJSON(df, pretty=FALSE) and now the plumber api gives the correct JSON format as default. Indeed I double encoded as you mentioned.

Comment: I suppose this is also what you mentioned with Store the data itself instead myvar <<- df. The reason I use myvar <<- df is that I have two code scripts. The first is looping and generating the dataframe. The second is to host the json-string.